Apply listchars to concealed text by vimtex
I am writing LaTeX with vimtex conceal feature, and need to distinguish between the regular space U+0020 versus the non breaking space U+00A0. Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Space U+0020
Non Breaking Space U+00A0
LaTeX Space\ U+0020
LaTeX Non Breaking Space~U+00A0

\end{document}

Unfortunately StackExchange editor automatically replaced non breaking space by regular space, so copy & paste will not suffice here.
My vimrc contains set listchars=space:·,nbsp:␣,leadmultispace:»\ ,trail:·.
Here is how the document looks without conceal, i.e., conceallevel = 0,

while below is with conceal, i.e., conceallevel = 2,

We can see on line 5 and 6 both space and nbsp are properly displayed as · and ␣, since they are raw characters. 
But on line 7 and 8, it seems listchars does not apply to concealed texts, i.e., cchar.
My question is that is it possible to apply listchars to cchar?
Tried modifying the cchar to U+00A0 on https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/ac0a41b297a70c101df89bc9c8d43341ba00fd4f/autoload/vimtex/syntax/core.vim#L2204, since currently vimtex does not distinguish the two types of spaces in conceal, still the same outcome. Or I can change it straight to ␣, but then the highlight group is different from listchars, which requires more hacking.
Felt this is more of a vim issue instead of the plugin, so here we are and any comments are welcome.

Interesting. For the times you need to distinguish, doesn’t it make more sense to not have conceal on?

@D.BenKnoble Yes that's an option for sure, just want to know if using the builtin listchars is possible.
